# What method is called when UITabBarController shows first tab on screen? viewDidAppear doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have `UITabBarController` as the "Is Initial View Controller" in the storyboard. When it appears on screen, along appears the view of the leftmost tab. I have the following method in the implementation of the controller of said tab:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"view controller - first tab - appeared");
}
```

This is only called when I manually switch to the first tab and not when it first loads.

My question is - what method is called in the controller of the first tab on first load of the application?

#### Edit - Bizarre behaviour?

When the first tab appears on screen `viewDidLoad` gets called and everything is fine, but `viewDidAppear` isn't called until a manual tab change. Whereas other tabs on their first appearance, call both the `viewDidLoad` **AND** `viewDidAppear` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad]
      NSLog(@"view controller - first tab - appeared");
}
```

Comment: This does produce the intended result, although it is a bit strange - why isn't `viewDidAppear` called?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is what you are trying to do in that method because it is in a different part of the lifecycle.

I have a table that has its accessory checkmark turned on and off based upon the model. In `viewDidLoad`, the table puts all checkmarks in automatically (which is the default).

Basically I am changing the `accessoryType` on the cells before they are initially displayed and my changes are overwritten.  In `viewDidAppear` I go through the data and change them.  Since this method is never called, the first tab screen is always incorrect.

I was able to fix this by using `viewDidAppear` on all tabs and the `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to set the accessory type when tab view is first displayed

Comment: I think this would be more informative if you'd mention how the lifecycle actually works for the `UITabBarController`. In any case, thanks :)